# SQL query to group by a column and show its result in rows with group by another column and display results in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want the data in a particular format as grouping on one column it will display its result into rows and also grouping another column and display result in rows corresponding to that grouping of rows.

The data is in the format :

```
id  type    insertdate             forUser
------------------------------------------
1   Suit    2020-08-24 13:16:42.000 sw
2   Suit    2020-08-24 13:16:49.000 sw
3   Suit    2020-08-24 00:46:31.773 sw
4   jacket  2020-08-24 13:17:15.000 sw
5   jacket  2020-08-24 13:17:35.000 sw
6   jacket  2020-08-24 00:47:43.620 sw
7   jacket  2020-08-24 00:48:42.470 SK
8   Blazer  2020-08-24 13:19:19.000 SK
9   Blazer  2020-08-24 00:49:00.097 SK
10  Blazer  2020-08-24 00:49:07.130 SK
11  Blazer  2020-08-24 13:20:34.000 SK
12  indo    2020-08-24 13:21:15.000 SK
13  indo    2020-08-24 13:21:46.000 SK
14  indo    2020-08-24 13:21:59.000 SK
```

and I want the result in this format :

```
forUser suit jacket blazer indo
--------------------------------
SK      0     1     4       3
sw      3     3     0       0
```

I have no idea how to achieve it, can we use count with where clause:

```
select forUser, count(* where type='suit') 
from tblTurnSys
group by forUser
```

Comment: This technique of turning rows into columns is called a [pivot](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select forUser,
       sum(case when type = 'suit' then 1 else 0 end) as suit,
       sum(case when type = 'jacket' then 1 else 0 end) as jacket,
       sum(case when type = 'blazer' then 1 else 0 end) as blazer,
       sum(case when type = 'indo' then 1 else 0 end) as indo
from t
group by forUser;
```

Comment: what if we have unknown number of users?

Comment: but the column [type] can have more than 4 different items

Comment: Do you mean users, or types, @SowmyadharGourishetty . This will have no problems for any number of users.

Comment: sorry it is `type` @Larnu

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty we have group by clause,it will take care.

Comment: what if we have another type `test1, test2 .... testn`?

Comment: Then you need a dynamic pivot, @SowmyadharGourishetty , as demonstrated in the duplicate. How to pivot data (dynamically) has been ask 1000's of times on Stack Overflow, and the answer is still this (more or less) the same.